# Can't run jupyterhub in docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I launch the jupyterhub service as follow (command is taken from [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart-docker.html#starting-jupyterhub-with-docker)):

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub
```

I also tried this one from the [troubleshooting](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#jupyterhub-docker-container-not-accessible-at-localhost) section:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

But I have an error message when open `localhost:8000`:

```
This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have encountered an [open issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2843) occurring on the latest docker image which seems to be broken.

As a workaround you can use version `1.0.0` which is working fine.

Use this docker run command instead:

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub:1.0.0 jupyterhub`

As an advice, when you need to debug cases like this you faced, avoid using detach mode(`-d` flag) so that you are able to see container's logs.